# How do you say 'You saying so doesn't make it so' in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

So, how do you say "You saying so doesn't make it so" in Latin? I think it would be a literal translation of Croatian "Tvoje to reći to ne čini", *Tuum id dicere id non facit*, but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you want a literal or idiomatic translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest a non-literal translation to capture the idea:

> *Quamvis dicas, non fit.*
> However much you say it, it does not happen.

Or even more pithily:

> *Dicas, non fit.*
> You may say so, but it does not happen.

The point of these approaches is to convert "you saying so" to a concessive clause, which strikes me as something idiomatic for this purpose.
Brevity also gives the message strength.
Concessive clauses can be introduced [with](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/concessive-clauses) or [without](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/hortatory-subjunctive) a conjunction; see the two grammar links for details.

If the conclusion is not about happening but being, then replace *fit* with *est*.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Maybe *Rem affirmando vera non fit* vel aliquid huius modi?! (I suppose this should have been said to Cicero on many an occasion, but goodness only knows what the person would have said!)

Comment: Or to [Augustus](https://mobile.twitter.com/tutubuslatinus/status/1328791188929880066) ...