# Is "Te id dicente id non fit." good Latin for "You saying so does not make it so."?

Tags: syntax, ablative-absolute

Is "Te id dicente id non fit." good Latin for "You saying so does not make it so."? There are a couple of things I am not sure about it. When the participle is in ablative ("dicente"), which case does its object go? I put it in accusative ("id"), but I am not sure (in Croatian, it is the genitive). Should you use singular ("id" and "fit") or plural ("ea" and "fiunt") here? Can absolute ablative be used to mean cause, or does it always mean time? Can personal pronouns even be used in ablative absolute?

Comment: There is [a separate question on translating that English phrase to Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15133/79), but it doesn't discuss the validity of your suggested translation.